# How to set the favorite star icon to ON when clicked and OFF when again clicked in android

Tags: android

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)
My Activity that has list of quotes is as follow.

```
package bank.quotes.famous;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class QuotesActivity extends FamousQuotesActivity  { 
     @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  { 

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
         setContentView(R.layout.quoteslayout); 

         CheckBox favButton = (CheckBox)findViewById( R.id.favbutton );
```

I have tried adding your code here with no success.
My xml is as below, >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="856dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout08"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/forquotesgrey" >



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="@string/albertquote"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="@string/alberteinstein"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/favbutton"
                    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView21"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow06"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/forquotesgrey" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="@string/stevequote"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="@string/stevejob"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/CheckBox01"
                    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

If a user likes a quote then, it should go to Favorite activity. Also the fav button should always glow if is user favorite. This is how favorite button works, isn't it? This my first time adding a favorite button so I have less idea of doing it. If you could help me I would really appreciate that.
Thank You.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use stateful drawables you'll find it easier to skin a ToggleButton or CheckBox than an ImageButton.

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/star" 
    style="?android:attr/starStyle" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. But what am I suppose put instead of "someObject"? And I tried using toggle button but it shows its default "off" icon. But I want sth like Star icon which glows when clicked. Can you show that?

Comment: Say you are marking a book as a favorite.  someObject would be your model object like Book, Music, or Recipe.  someObject.isFav() would return true or false if this object is a favorite for this user.  toggleFavorite() would merely flip the boolean on that object when called.  ToggleButton or Checkbox would work you just need to style it.  I've modified my answer for Checkbox

Comment: Thank you again for the help. CheckBox code worked but I am quite not able to work out above code. When I put book instead of "someObject", I get error saying "book cannot be resolved"...same thing with "favButton". Should I do sth else beside this?

Comment: however creating "book" class didn't show error on book. and now i get "Cannot refer to a non-final variable favButton inside an inner class defined in a different method" error msg on favButton

Comment: What are you fav'ing in your program?  Local variables can't be referenced from anonymous inner classes without using the final keyword.  This is a Java language thing you can read about by googling for it.  someObject, book, whatever is for you fill in the blank here relative to what you are doing.

Comment: Changed the answer to remove the section you weren't understanding.

Comment: so I should put quote in it and then use it as final keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Find the button and set a click listener on it.
Here’s general code snippet.

```
add_fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isChecked)
                add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heartgroup);
            else
                add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_to_fav);

            isChecked = !isChecked;
        }

    });
```